# Disable/Enable OSB proxy service via WLST

Tags: service, proxy, wlst

I'm trying to automate one of the OSB proxy service using WLST in one of our environments and when i checked with Oracle support they routed me to this 3rd party python script which was tried by by others successfully long time back but since i'm new to this Python script, i'm having hard time. So wanted to see if someone can help me with correcting this script and fixing the issues. Provided below is the command i'm trying to disable/enable the OSB proxy service along with the whole script.

. ./setDomainEnv.sh (ran command to set the domain environment)

/appl/oracle/middleware/wls/12.2.1.4/oracle_common/common/bin

[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx bin]$ ./wlst.sh setproxystate.py -e t3://xxxxx:7002 xxxxxx project/proxyname

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):

(no code object) at line 0

File "/appl/oracle/middleware/wls/12.2.1.4/oracle_common/common/bin/setproxystate.py", line 60

```
        print("Disable Service")

        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**setproxystate.py script:**

#! /usr/bin/env python

import getopt

import sys

import os

from com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration import SessionManagementMBean

from com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration import ALSBConfigurationMBean

from com.bea.wli.config import Ref

from com.bea.wli.monitoring import StatisticType

from com.bea.wli.sb.util import Refs

from com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration import CommonServiceConfigurationMBean

from com.bea.wli.sb.util import EnvValueTypes

wl_user="weblogic"

verbose=False

#########################################################################################

def ConnectToWLS(u, p, h):

print("Connect to " + h + " as user " + u)

connect(u,p, h)

domainRuntime()

def DisconnectFromWLS():

print("Disconnect")

disconnect()

def CreateOSBSession():

sessionName  = "SetProxyStateSession_" + str(System.currentTimeMillis())

sessionMBean = findService(SessionManagementMBean.NAME, SessionManagementMBean.TYPE)

sessionMBean.createSession(sessionName)

print("OSB Session Created: " + sessionName)

return sessionMBean, sessionName

def ActivateSession(b, n, s, a):

print("Activate OSB Session: " + n)

b.activateSession(n, a + " " + s)

def FindService(f, s, session, n):

print("Find proxy service: " + f + "/" + s)

pxyConf = "ProxyServiceConfiguration." + n

mbean = findService(pxyConf, 'com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.ProxyServiceConfigurationMBean')

alsbSession = findService(ALSBConfigurationMBean.NAME + "." + n, ALSBConfigurationMBean.TYPE)

alsbCore = findService(ALSBConfigurationMBean.NAME, ALSBConfigurationMBean.TYPE)

allRefs=alsbCore.getRefs(Ref.DOMAIN)

for ref in allRefs.iterator():

```
typeId = ref.getTypeId()

if typeId == "BusinessService" :

    name=ref.getFullName()

    uris=alsbSession.getEnvValue(ref, EnvValueTypes.SERVICE_URI_TABLE, None)

  #  print (name)

   # print (uris)

   # print
```

folderRef = Refs.makeParentRef(f + "/")

serviceRef = Refs.makeProxyRef(folderRef, s)

return serviceRef, mbean

def setStateService(b, s, a):

```
if a == 'disable':

print("Disable Service")

b.disableService(s)
```

else:

```
print("Enable Service")

b.enableService(s)
```

#########################################################################################

def usage():

print ("Usage: Enable/Disable Proxy services")

print ("setProxyState [-d|-e] [-v] [-f list-of-proxy-services] admin-url wls-password [proxy-service]")

print ("-v verbose output")

print ("-d disable the proxy state")

print ("-e enable the proxy state")

print ("-f file with a list of proxy services")

def main():

############################################################

### Parse Arguments

proxy_file=""

noofargs = 3

try:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "vdehf:", ["help"])



for o, a in opts:

  if o == '-h':

    usage()

    exit()

  elif o == '-v':

    global verbose

    verbose = True

  elif o == '-d':

    state = "disable"

  elif o == '-e':

    state = "enable"

  elif o == '-f':

    proxy_file = a

    noofargs = noofargs - 1

  else:

    print ("Unknown argument.")

    print ("")

    usage()

    exit()



if len(args) != noofargs:

  print ("Invalid number of arguments.")

  print ("")

  usage()

  exit()



admin_server = args[0]

wl_password = args[1]



if len(proxy_file) > 0:

  setStateListOfProxyService(proxy_file, state, wl_password, admin_server)

else:

  proxy_service = args[2]

  setStateOfProxyService(proxy_service, state, wl_password, admin_server)
```

except getopt.GetoptError as err:

```
# print help information and exit:

print (str(err))

print ("")

usage()
```

############################################################

def print(m):

```
if verbose:

print (m)
```

def setStateListOfProxyService(pfile, stateOnOff, wl_password, admin_server):

try:

```
ConnectToWLS("weblogic", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx")



file = open(pfile, "r")

osbSession, sessionName = CreateOSBSession()



appliedServices = ""

for line in file.readlines():

  line = line.lstrip().rstrip()

  print("Read line: " + line)

if line.find("#") < 0 and len(line) > 0:

    relativePath = os.path.dirname(line)

    pServiceName = os.path.basename(line)

    appliedServices = appliedServices + " " + pServiceName

    service, sessionBean = FindService(relativePath, pServiceName, osbSession, sessionName)

    setStateService(sessionBean, service, stateOnOff)



file.close()

ActivateSession(osbSession, sessionName, appliedServices, stateOnOff)



DisconnectFromWLS()
```

except:

```
print ("Unexpected error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])

dumpStack()

raise
```

def setStateOfProxyService(pservice, stateOnOff, wl_password, admin_server):

try:

```
ConnectToWLS("weblogic", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx")

osbSession, sessionName = CreateOSBSession()

relativePath = os.path.dirname(pservice)

pServiceName = os.path.basename(pservice)

print ("relativePath :",relativePath)

print ("pServiceName :",pServiceName)

service, sessionBean = FindService(relativePath, pServiceName, osbSession, sessionName)

setStateService(sessionBean, service, stateOnOff)

ActivateSession(osbSession, sessionName, pServiceName, stateOnOff)

DisconnectFromWLS()
```

except:

```
print ("Unexpected error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])

dumpStack()

raise
```

############################################################

main()

exit()

I was trying to execute the script and getting a lot of syntax errors for the python script

[xxxxxx@xxxxxxx bin]$ ./wlst.sh setproxystate.py -e t3://xxxxx:7002 xxxxxx project/proxyname

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):

(no code object) at line 0

File "/appl/oracle/middleware/wls/12.2.1.4/oracle_common/common/bin/setproxystate.py", line 60

```
        print("Disable Service")

        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).